# Calculate new row based on old row value using dplyr and not showing NA for first value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply, lag

my sample data :

```
structure(list(state = c("Himachal_Pradesh", "Himachal_Pradesh", "Himachal_Pradesh", "Himachal_Pradesh", "Himachal_Pradesh", 
"Himachal_Pradesh"), town_names = c("town_a", "town_a", "town_a", 
"town_a", "town_a", "town_a"), sales_growth = c(67784.15767, 
67784.15767, 67784.15767, 67784.15767, 67784.15767, 67784.15767
), key = c("growth_in_2019", "growth_in_2019", "growth_in_2019", 
"growth_in_2019", "growth_in_2019", "growth_in_2019"), value = c(0.0220237807164989, 
0.0220237807164989, 0.0220237807164989, 0.0220237807164989, 0.0220237807164989, 
0.0220237807164989), year = c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019"), dates = structure(c(17896, 17927, 17955, 17986, 
18016, 18047), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("state", "town1", 
"key"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:5), group_sizes = 6L, biggest_group_size = 6L, labels = structure(list(
    state = "Himachal_Pradesh", town_names = "town_a", key = "growth_in_2019"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("state", "town1", "key"
), drop = TRUE))
```

I'm trying to calculate a new columns called growth
`Formula = traffic*(1+value)` for first row and for second row: it has to grab previous row value and then calculate :`previous_row*(1+value)`.It has to be a increasing order.

```
nv2 <- nv2 %>%
    group_by(state, town_names,dates) %>%
    mutate(formula = sales_growth*(1+value)) %>%
    mutate(formula = formula*(1+value))

state             town_names        dates      formula
Himachal_pradesh    town_a        2018-12-31     69,277.02
Himachal_pradesh    town_a        2019-01-31     70,802.76
Himachal_pradesh    town_a        2019-02-28     72,362.10
Himachal_pradesh    town_a        2019-03-31     73,955.79
Himachal_pradesh    town_a        2019-04-30     75,584.58
```